# Determine the voltage drops across the capacitor

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, discharge

I am having troubles with one type of tasks when preparing for an exam. I think I get the way to solve it when t = 0, but I don't really know what my approach should be when t>0.

Task: [image]

That is how I solved it:
[image: my solution]

//Edit
Updated version for t>0. I think it might be correct now. Is it?

[image: after t>0]

Comment: Why your Rth is 3R in the second case? Also as you can see because of 2/3E > 2/5E the capacitor will be charged from 2/5E to 2/3E. Not discharged.

Comment: @G36 As far as I remember we don't have to take these resistors that are in branch where capacitor is placed, so we are left with 2 resistors (R and 2R that are serially connected), but I can be wrong.

Comment: Why? to find the time constant you need to find the resistance seen from the capacitor terminals.  And from the capacitor point of view, the R and 2R are not connected in series.   https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377467/why-is-the-voltage-of-a-capacitor-equal-to-the-voltage-of-a-battery-connected-it/377478#377478

Comment: Okey, so Rth will be equal to 8/3R right?

Comment: Yep, Rth = 8/3R

Comment: And then  Uc = [ (8/3R) / (Zc + 8/3R)] am I correct?

Comment: No, you are wrong.

Comment: @G36 You should've linked to [this](https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/145/018/274.jpg) as you said that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the first part (switch closed) right.  Then, the top R, the two R's in parallel, and the final R all form a voltaage divider with the C at that voltage.

When you open the switch, however, the C will charge to the full E; the current flowing through the two resistors now in 'parallel' with the C don't matter.  However, the rate at which it charges will be determined by all the resistors in series with C.

And, as usual, the solution will look like

$$V_0+ V_fe^{-f(r,c)t}$$