# Class A power amplifier, how to calculate base voltage after removing collector load

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amplifier

In the following circuit:

[image]

I calculated the base voltage by Vb = R2/(R1+R2)  Vcc  [stiffed voltage divider] , but then when I'm asked to calculate the total power from the power supply when we remove the load, the base voltage changes.

My question is why does the base voltage change after removing R_L and how do I calculate it? This is how the solution calculates it and this is what it says:

[image]

I don't understand how Thevnin's theorm is used here and why is it even used

Comment: Do you need a more thoroughly descriptive answer than what Cristobol provided? What he wrote is correct. But it may be assuming that you understand things you may not actually understand. Another way of putting this is: When you remove the load, there cannot be any collector current (obviously.) So now the emitter current equals the base current (which isn't true when the load is connected.) So the whole situation suddenly changes.

Comment: I understood what he meant yes, but I want to make sure I understand it correctly, if the emitter current is now the base current, does that affect the voltage divider because the current of the voltage divider is the same as the current that flows through the emitter resistors now?

Comment: The base current flows through those two DC resistors. Of course, you need Thevenin's for the base resistor pair to make things easier. Then you have an equivalent ideal voltage source along with an equivalent series resistance, then a diode, then the two emitter resistors to ground. So you can just sum up all that resistance, leaving just the Thevenin source voltage, one resistor, and one diode. Subtract the diode voltage from the Thevenin source voltage and that's the voltage that must be dropped across that remaining resistor. So you know the current (approximately, without Shockley eq.)

Comment: What I did was, I have the thevenin voltage with the thevenin resistance that comes from R1 and R2 , in series with a diode and the two emitter resistors, so now I used voltage divider to get the voltage across the two emitter resistors, then I added 0.7V to it to get the base voltage ,is that correct?

Comment: Also just to make sure I understand what Cristobol said, when the only current flowing through the emitter resistors is the base current, this means that the emitter resistors have to draw more voltage from the voltage divider because the current decreased, no?

Comment: Your words, such as "draw more voltage," bother me a lot because I frankly don't understand what you mean by them. Once you know the current (easily computed), you can simply multiply that current by each of the two emitter resistances to work out the voltage drop across each of them. Since you know one end of one of them is grounded, it should be very easy to work out the voltage at the capacitor and at the BJT emitter. So if that's what you are saying, then yes. But if that is not what you are saying, then no. I guess.

Comment: By drawing more voltage I mean that the emitter resistors will now participate with the other resistors connected to the 15V supply,  also in the circuit I'm only doing DC analysis to get the DC power, so I don't think there is even voltage across the capacitor, my goal is to get the voltage at the base Vb, which is across R2

Comment: Okay. I suspect this means you need a more descriptive answer than has been provided by Cristobol. It's obvious to me and I'm sure very obvious to Cristobol how you should get this -- just sum the drops across the two emitter resistors and add one diode drop and you are there -- but perhaps you need more? If so, then you need a very, very detailed approach to getting at your base voltage. I can provide it, but not right now. Perhaps in a couple of hours' time. Cristobol, in the meantime, might instead choose to expand that answer sufficiently to avoid my writing one.

Comment: Yes! That's how I did it, I just needed to understand the problem that Cristobol explained plus a confirmation that how I got Vb was correct to make sure I understand, thanks alot!

Comment: Before I write something here, would you please go [to this EESE answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/479350/38098) and read it? Then tell me if you follow the logic there and don't need me to repeat all of that. It has a collector load, so there will be a slightly different process to it. But what I want to make sure of is if you follow the Thevenin equivalence shown for the two base resistors in that answer. If so, that saves me space here. Or do you want me to duplicate that stuff, but apply it to your specific case?

Answer (score 1):

When \$R_L\$ is connected, \$R_{E1}\$ and \$R_{E2}\$ are fed predominantly by the collector current.  The base provides only a small fraction \$1/(\beta+1)\$ of that current.  In this case, the base voltage is primarily determined by \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.

When you disconnect \$R_L\$, there is no source for current to \$R_{E1}\$ and \$R_{E2}\$ except from the base.  This draws significant current from the voltage divider on 15V comprised of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$.  This is represented by its Thevenin equivalent so that the network can be analyzed as a series circuit.  The transistor, with no collector connection, is essentially a diode.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f98p2A.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When analyzing a transistor we need to use the following [relations](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_2.html):

- $$\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_\text{C}\tag1$$
- Transistor gain \$\beta\$:
  $$\beta=\frac{\text{I}_\text{C}}{\text{I}_\text{B}}\tag2$$
- Emitter voltage:
  $$\text{V}_\text{E}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3\tag3$$

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{B}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{x}=\text{I}_\text{C}+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\text{I}_6+\text{I}_7\\
\\
0=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_\text{x}+\text{I}_5
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

When we use and apply [KVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff's_voltage_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{in}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{C}=\frac{\text{V}_\text{x}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{E}=\frac{\text{V}_3-\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_6}\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\frac{\text{V}_4}{\text{R}_7}
\end{cases}\tag5
$$

When applying the set of equations to your circuit, I used Mathematica-code to solve for the unknowns:

```
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{VE == V1 - V3, IE == IB + IC, β == IC/IB, 
   I1 + I3 == IB + I2, I2 == I1 + I4, Ix == IC + I3, IE == I6 + I7, 
   I4 + I5 + I6 == 0, I7 == Ix + I5, I1 == (Vin - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1)/R2, I3 == (Vx - V1)/R3, IC == (Vx - V2)/R4, 
   IC == (V3 - V4)/R5, I6 == V4/R6, I7 == V4/R7}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5,
    I6, I7, IB, IC, IE, Ix, V1, V2, V3, V4}]]
```

Using that, I got the following result:

```
{{I1 -> (-R2 R3 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vin) + R3 R5 R7 Vin β + 
      R3 R6 Vin (R7 + (R5 + R7) β) + 
      R2 (Vin - Vx) (R5 R7 β + 
         R6 (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
      R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  I2 -> (R1 R3 R6 VE + R1 R3 R7 VE + R3 R6 R7 Vin + 
      R1 R6 R7 Vx + (R6 R7 + R5 (R6 + R7)) (R3 Vin + 
         R1 Vx) β)/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 + 
      R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  I3 -> (-R2 (Vin - Vx) (R5 R7 β + 
         R6 (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)) + 
      R1 (-R2 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vx) + R5 R7 Vx β + 
         R6 Vx (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 +
       R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  I4 -> (R1 R3 (R6 + R7) VE + R2 R3 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vin) + 
      R1 R5 R7 Vx β + R1 R6 Vx (R7 + (R5 + R7) β) - 
      R2 (Vin - Vx) (R5 R7 β + 
         R6 (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
      R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  I5 -> (-R1 (R5 R7 Vx β - R2 R7 (VE - Vx) (1 + β) + 
         R3 VE (R6 - R7 β) + R6 Vx (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)) + 
      R2 (-R3 (VE - Vin) (R6 - R7 β) + (Vin - 
            Vx) (R5 R7 β + 
            R6 (R7 + (R5 + R7) β))))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + 
      R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  I6 -> -((R7 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) (1 + β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  I7 -> -((R6 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) (1 + β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  IB -> -(((R6 + R7) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 + 
        R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  IC -> -(((R6 + R7) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) β)/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  IE -> -(((R6 + R7) (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) (1 + β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  Ix -> (R2 R6 R7 (-Vin + Vx) + 
      R2 (-R3 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vin) - (R5 R6 + (R5 + R6) R7) (Vin - 
            Vx)) β + 
      R1 (R6 R7 Vx + (-R3 (R6 + R7) VE + 
            R5 R6 Vx + (R5 + R6) R7 Vx) β - 
         R2 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vx) (1 + β)))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + 
      R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  V1 -> (R2 (R1 R3 R6 VE + R1 R3 R7 VE + R3 R6 R7 Vin + 
        R1 R6 R7 Vx + (R6 R7 + R5 (R6 + R7)) (R3 Vin + 
           R1 Vx) β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 +
       R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  V2 -> (R1 (R2 R3 R6 + R3 R6 R7 + R2 (R3 + R6) R7) Vx + 
      R1 ((R2 + R3) R4 (R6 + R7) VE + (R3 R5 R6 + R3 (R5 + R6) R7 + 
            R2 (R5 R6 + (R5 + R6) R7 - R4 (R6 + R7))) Vx) β + 
      R2 R3 (R6 R7 Vx + (R4 (R6 + R7) (VE - Vin) + R6 R7 Vx + 
            R5 (R6 + R7) Vx) β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
      R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
      R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
         R5 (R6 + R7)) β), 
  V3 -> -(((R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) (R5 R7 β + 
          R6 (R7 + (R5 + R7) β)))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β)), 
  V4 -> -((R6 R7 (R1 (R2 + R3) VE + R2 R3 (VE - Vin) - 
          R1 R2 Vx) (1 + β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + 
        R1 R2 R6 R7 + R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
        R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
           R5 (R6 + R7)) β))}}
```

Which means that the base voltage is given by:

```
V1 -> (R2 (R1 R3 R6 VE + R1 R3 R7 VE + R3 R6 R7 Vin + 
            R1 R6 R7 Vx + (R6 R7 + R5 (R6 + R7)) (R3 Vin + 
               R1 Vx) β))/(R1 R2 R3 R6 + R1 R2 R3 R7 + R1 R2 R6 R7 +
           R1 R3 R6 R7 + 
          R2 R3 R6 R7 + (R2 R3 + R1 (R2 + R3)) (R6 R7 + 
             R5 (R6 + R7)) β)
```

> So, as you can see the base voltage is independent on \$\text{R}_4\$.

---

Using your values, with:

1. $$\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_1}\space\space\space\Longrightarrow\space\space\space\text{R}_1=\frac{1}{\text{s}\cdot22\cdot10^{-6}}=\frac{10^6}{22\text{s}}\tag6$$
2. $$\text{R}_7=\frac{1}{\text{sC}_2}\space\space\space\Longrightarrow\space\space\space\text{R}_7=\frac{1}{\text{s}\cdot100\cdot10^{-6}}=\frac{10^4}{\text{s}}\tag7$$
3. $$\text{V}_\text{in}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[250\cdot10^{-3}\cdot\sin\left(2000\pi t\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{500\pi}{4000000\pi^2+\text{s}^2}\tag8$$
4. $$\text{V}_\text{x}=\mathcal{L}_t\left[15\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{15}{\text{s}}\tag9$$

And I used the assumptions:

1. $$\beta=100\tag{10}$$
2. $$\text{V}_\text{E}=\text{V}_1-\text{V}_3=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{7}{10}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\tag{11}$$

And the base voltage is then given by:

```
V1 -> (16500 (200000000 \[Pi]^2 (168850 + 117 s) + 
      50 s^2 (168850 + 117 s) + 
      11 \[Pi] s^2 (557000 + 369 s)))/(s (4000000 \[Pi]^2 + 
      s^2) (39103000000 + 3 s (78051500 + 44649 s)))
```

And in the time domain it is equal to:

```
(33 E^(-((250 (156103 + 5 Sqrt[602265097]) t)/
    44649)) (1529044609 (47 (-216366939635 + 
           8620393 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
        22 (-335461659029 + 13542139 Sqrt[602265097]) \[Pi]) + 
     20338492325690 E^((250 (156103 + 5 Sqrt[602265097]) t)/
      44649) (1529044609 + 177411483153 \[Pi]^2 + 
        287068780944 \[Pi]^4) + 
     9 \[Pi]^2 (926482189799 (-216366939635 + 
           8620393 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
        16236 \[Pi] (39103 (-4277888983991 + 
              88624051 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
           92334132 (-216366939635 + 
              8620393 Sqrt[602265097]) \[Pi])) - 
     E^((2500 Sqrt[602265097] t)/
      44649) (71865096623 (216366939635 + 
           8620393 Sqrt[
            602265097]) + \[Pi] (33638981398 (335461659029 + 
              13542139 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
           9 \[Pi] (926482189799 (216366939635 + 
                 8620393 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
              16236 \[Pi] (39103 (4277888983991 + 
                    88624051 Sqrt[602265097]) + 
                 92334132 (216366939635 + 
                    8620393 Sqrt[602265097]) \[Pi])))) + 
     1036216371871604 E^((250 (156103 + 5 Sqrt[602265097]) t)/
      44649) \[Pi] ((21780371 + 47178126 \[Pi]^2) Cos[2000 \[Pi] t] + 
        33 \[Pi] (7030003 + 11982168 \[Pi]^2) Sin[
          2000 \[Pi] t])))/(188402976703928 (1529044609 + 
     177411483153 \[Pi]^2 + 287068780944 \[Pi]^4))
```

Plotting, gives:

[image]