# Maximum peak current swing (Class A amplifier)

Tags: power, transistors, amplifier

For a class A amplifier, the Q point is centered as shown:

[image]

and the maximum signal that can be obtained is when the peak value of the current is Icq and peak value of VCE is VCEQ

[image]

Now when we calculate the 'maximum peak voltage swing' and the 'maximum peak current swing' This is what the book does

[image]

We just said that the peak value of the collector current is Icq in the second picture, so why is it that Ic(max) = VCEQ/Rc  in the last picture?

Same with Vc(max), what's the difference here?

Also, if there is no difference, why do we divide VCEQ by Rc to get collector current?

note: Rc is the ac collector resistance, Vc is the collector voltage, from floyd's electronic devices ninth edition page 343

Comment: What is VC(max) in your book and why do they use the quiescent current to find it? I'm certainly confused.

Comment: Vc(max) is the peak output voltage (the amplified voltage on the load)

Comment: maybe because the Q point is centred, so the maximum peak to peak current that results is 2Icq, so the peak current is Icq, multiply that by Rc to get Vc(max) , what I don't get is why when we want Ic(max) , we divide VCEQ by Rc

Comment: Well, I don't get that, either. I think we need a lot more context from the source material you are reading. I mean, suppose Vceq is equal to Vcc. Then, obviously, there's no quiescent current at all (no voltage drop across Rc.) But that equation would suggest Vcc/Rc is the quiescent current. And that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, did you read my last comment to your question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/483349/38098)?

Comment: I did, the experimental validation part was a bit hard for me though, I understood some of the theory to some extent, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around it.

For this current question, your suggestion that when Vceq equals Vcc renders the formula senseless made me confused now, I don't even know how to bring more context to this, maybe I don't fully understand the notation.

Comment: Yeah. I think either, (1) you don't understand the notation and are misrepresenting what you are reading; or, (2) there is something fundamentally wrong with the source materials you are reading. The example I gave you is "extreme" of course -- no one would bias an amplifier like that. But it is ***possible*** to bias it like that and, in such an extreme case, your formula obviously doesn't provide a sound answer. So there is a break in the logic applied or a break in the assumptions entering into it. One or the other.

Comment: I think Vc(max) being equal to Icq * Rc cannot exceed or equal Vcc because Vc(max) is a constant value that is due to the peak ac current which is Icq, times Rc, and we cannot let Vc(max) = Vcc [not a variable] maybe?

Comment: A CE amplifier is in a state with Q point centred (Icq,VCEQ), if we apply an input signal, Vce can swing above the Q point till the cutoff point and below the Q point till the saturation point, Ic swings above Icq till saturation and below Icq till cutoff, so the maximum current flowing through Rc will be 2Icq, which means that the peak value is Icq, this means that the peak value of the collector voltage is Icq times Rc, am I making sense or is there still something wrong?

Comment: There isn't one way of seeing all this stuff. It's actually a lot more nuanced than these simple equations. For example, there is NO POSSIBLE way anyone would design an isolated stage for Ic going from 0 to Ic(sat). The distortion would be HORRIBLE. (Global NFB could help.) And you don't drive the BJT into saturation -- that's also pretty bad to do. (Usually, anyway.) I've written a lot on this topic, so have others. But to help you with the material you are reading, we need to see it, I think.

Comment: The material is Floyd's electronic devices 9th edition starting from page 340 , http://www.te.kmutnb.ac.th/~msn/225303report56.pdf

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you remember all the discussion in the previous chapter about upper and lower case lettering? You need to keep that context when writing out your questions. For example, when I see Rc do I assume this is RC (the collector resistor itself) or RC || RL (and other factors) that apply to the AC version of it? You might be copying, correctly, from the book. But we honestly don't have any idea if you are just being sloppy (like I often am) or if you are being precise in a very narrow way.

Comment: The problem is I want to use math symbols in here but it doesn't work I don't know why, for example $R_{c}$ and $R_{C}$, but yes I do mean R with a small c

Comment: Because the dollar-sign was used as a dollar-sign in earlier periods on EESE, they decided NOT to accept the dollar-sign for math. You have to use a backslash and then a dollar-sign as a "pair of characters", instead. Or else use a pair of dollar-signs. The sign character by itself doesn't work here. (except it really rare places, which i don't want to discuss.) Regardless, you would still need to clarify things. I still might read \$R_c\$ as just the DC collector resistor, because I wouldn't know if you knew. So you have to write, as well as use variable names.

Comment: Another thing is that when talking about output power, there is the matter of where exactly that power is dissipated. Some in the DC collector resistor, some in the BJT itself, some in the load resistance, etc. Or maybe just the load portion is the real question, depending upon context. Everything requires context.

Comment: In the last picture, it says that the power is the product of load current and load voltage, so its the power dissipated in the load, no? My question is why Ic(max) is related by VCEQ/Rc ?

Comment: Do you see ANY curve/chart that shows \$I_{c(max)}\$? I see \$I_{c(sat)}\$. But not \$I_{c(max)}\$.

Comment: No, I only see $$I_{c}$$ bounded by $$I_{c(sat)}$$ and zero

Comment: So what do you think the meaning of \$I_{c(max)}\$ is? Is it the same as \$I_{c(sat)}\$, or something different? (I'm asking, because I don't know for sure.)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm trying to figure out what it is, in the second picture there is a paragraph saying  that the peak value of collector current is Icq, would that mean that Ic(max) is Icq or is it Ic(sat), I don't know I'm really confused.

Comment: Those statements are very, very poorly worded. The writer is not a very good one. It could be that what is really meant is that: "The AC peak collector current, with respect to the quiescent collector current, is \$I_{CQ}\$." In this case, since we know that \$I_{CQ}\$ is halfway between the DC max and 0, that the AC peak would, in fact, just be \$I_{CQ}\$. But if so, the text writer should go out and save the world the trouble and just shoot themselves for poor writing skills

Comment: Do you have any idea what would dividing VCEQ by \$ R_{c} \$ yield in a normal class A common emitter amplifier?

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I finally took a moment to download and read a few pages of your book. I wasn't sure before, but I really think you did a good job in writing up the question now that I've had a chance to skim it. You selected out the right parts.

The two equations you are discussing in the **Output Power** section are prefaced by the comment that the "maximum *unclipped* ac signal occurs when the Q-point is centered." This is important and you selected out the right figure, Figure 7.2(b), which diagrams this exact situation.

So let me take your diagram and add something to it:

[image]

I believe the authors have defined \$I_{c}=I_{C}-I_{C_Q}\$ and \$V_{c}=V_{CE}-V_{{CE}_Q}\$. And they are then saying that \$I_{c(max)}\$ is the peak magnitude above (or below) the center-line of \$I_{C_Q}\$ and that \$V_{c(max)}\$ is similarly the peak magnitude above (or below) the center-line of \$V_{{CE}_Q}\$.

---

As \$V_{CE}=V_{{CE}_Q}+R_c\cdot\left(I_{C_Q}-I_{C}\right)\$ and therefore \$V_c=R_c\cdot\left(I_{C_Q}-I_{C}\right)\$, \$V_c\$ has a maximum value when \$I_C=0\:\text{A}\$ and thus it must be that \$V_{c(max)}=R_c\cdot\left(I_{C_Q}-0\:\text{A}\right)=R_c\cdot I_{C_Q}\$

---

As \$I_C=I_{C_Q}+\frac{V_{{CE}_Q}-V_{C}}{R_c}\$ and therefore \$I_c=\frac{V_{{CE}_Q}-V_{C}}{R_c}\$, \$I_c\$ has a maximum value when \$V_C=0\:\text{V}\$ and thus it must be that \$I_{c(max)}=\frac{V_{{CE}_Q}-0\:\text{V}}{R_c}=\frac{V_{{CE}_Q}}{R_c}\$

---

I believe that's what the book is telling you.

They probably should have said \$V_{ce}=V_{CE}-V_{{CE}_Q}\$ instead of using \$V_c\$ and also should have said \$V_{ce(max)}\$ instead of \$V_{c(max)}\$.

That was what confused me until I skimmed the four pages I needed to see. I thought they were talking about the collector voltage in the first equation.