# Idea behind Thevenin equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, short-circuit, thevenin

As i know, we find a thevenin equivalent resistance by finding open-circuit voltage and short-circuit current and then divide these two. I have looked on wikipedia and other sources but could not find an answer. On these websites they only tell how to do it. How opening a circuit and shorting a circuit helps us to find an equivalent resistance? What is a physical fact behind this idea?

Comment: See [this](https://spinningnumbers.org/a/thevenin-proof.html). Go to the bottom of the page and read up a little.

Comment: Maybe this explanation will help you https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377467/why-is-the-voltage-of-a-capacitor-equal-to-the-voltage-of-a-battery-connected-it/377478#377478

Comment: @jonk What a great source!

Comment: @Neil_UK Yeah. I liked it, too. It's a nice segue into the ideas involved.

Comment: *finding open-circuit current and short-circuit voltage* - don't you mean the other way round?

Comment: Yes i misspelled it. Also thanks for everyone for comments. They are really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

By opening and shorting the port, you are finding the extreme ends of the I_V curve.