# Calculating load resistor for maximum power

Tags: power, homework

[image]

How would I go about solving this? I cannot even begin solving this.

EDIT 1:
Thank you all of you I got it:

\$R_{Th}=(\frac{1}{6k}+\frac{1}{12k})^{-1}+2k = 6kΩ\$

Find the potentials at both the nodes connecting the \$12kΩ\$ resistor to the rest of the circuit. \$6V\$ at the top node and \$2V\$ at the bottom. Their difference gives \$V_{Th}\$:
\$V_{Th}=6-2=4V\$

The maximum power transfers to the load resistor when \$R_{Th}=R_{L}\$
Using \$P_{L}=\frac{V_{Th}^{2}}{R_{Th}}\$ the power is found to be \$1.5mW\$

Edit 2:
Sorry, the power is actually found to be \$0.6667mW\$

Comment: You need to use a Thevenin theorem. So, 1 remove RL and find Vab voltage (Vab = Vth). 2 - Find Rth resistance seen from AB terminal (without Rth) or Short AB terminals and find this short circuit current Isc and calculate Rth = Vth/Isc.   3 - To get max power transfer you need to have Rth = RL https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377467/why-is-the-voltage-of-a-capacitor-equal-to-the-voltage-of-a-battery-connected-it/377478#377478

Comment: This is not Chegg. We expect you to make a significant effort yourself and to show your work. If you really, truly "cannot even begin" then you might consider changing your major.

Comment: Hi, Mhf do you know how to figure out the Thevenin equivalent circuit at points A, B?

Comment: Any progress in finding Vth and Rth?

Comment: @G36 Yes, I was on it since the last 6 hours, and I learned and practised Thevenin and Norton circuit equivalent theorems and understood. But don't fully understand why there is a max power transmission when Rth = RL. The link to your answer is extremely useful and I will go through it carefully again.

I will post a picture of the calculations I did right now.

I can't thank you enough.

Comment: I added my progress to the question as an Edit

Comment: It should be easy to see that for R_load = 0Ω or R_load = ∞  We have zero power transferred to the load P_load = 0W, because R_load = 0Ω means that V_load = 0V and I_load = V_source/R_source, so that P_load = V_load x I_load = 0W. But Rload = ∞ means that V_load = V_source and I_load = 0A , so that again P_load = 0W. There has to be a maximum in between. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/maximum-power-transfer-theorem And math proof https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem#Calculus-based_proof_for_purely_resistive_circuits

Comment: How do you get 1.5mW?

Comment: @G36 Thanks for the explanation.

Whoops, my bad. Thevenin's resistance is 4v I took it as 6v. It should be 0.666...mW = 0.7mW

Comment: do the math again because Rth is 6k and Vth = 4V

Comment: @G36
 \$ R_{th} = 6k \$
 \$ V_{th} = 4V \$
 \$ P_{L} = \frac{V^{2}}{R}  \$
There is the \$  R_{th} \$ and the  \$ R_{L} \$ in series in the circuit with the same resistance. So the  \$ V_{Th} \$ is equally split between the two. So  \$ R_{L} \$ receives  \$ 2V \$, So the power is:
 \$ P_{L} = \frac{2^{2}}{6000} = 6.6667*10^{-4} = 0.66667mW \$

Comment: You re right, this time I made the mistake I use the \$P_{MAX} = \frac{V_{TH}^2}{R_L}\$ insted of this   \$P_{MAX} = \frac{V_{TH}^2}{4R_L}\$

Comment: @G36 Thank you! I highly appreciated all your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Find the Thévenin voltage and resistance as usual (with RL disconnected, looking into A and B).

Then calculate the power dissipation in the load resistor as a function of the load resistance.

Differentiate that equation and set to zero to find the maxima (or minima, but it will be a maxima).

Here is a plot of the function (arbitrary values of source resistance and voltage and range of load resistance)-  power on the Y axis, load resistance on the X axis:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Start with determining the theravin voltage source equivalent to points A and B, with it derived to this point, the maximum power resistance will be the same as the equivalent theravin resistance.

Comment: Did you mean Thevenin voltage?

Comment: A theravin voltage source has a voltage and a series resistance, the maximum load will be the same as that resistance

Comment: No, the word is "Thevenin".

Answer (score -1):

My answer based on understanding was too radical for at least one of you. So I'll solve it another way:  There is current coming out of that 6V voltage source.
100% of the current flows through the 6k resistor. 
The current is shared / split between the 12k resistor and the Load-arm.

Making RL = 0 will give maximum current and minimum voltage. (power = 0)
Making the RL open circuit will give maximum voltage and no current (power = 0)

So, what's the ideal current /voltage sharing arrangement with this 12k   resistor ?.   (hint, it's 12k)

Comment: Saying it twice doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Read the words above Sphero's graph, or ask your mum to do it for you: "arbitrary values of source resistance and voltage"