# Thévenin's Theorem - What to do when ending up with a voltage source in paralell with one resistor?

Tags: thevenin, norton

I want to find the Thévenin and Norton equivalents for the circuit below.

[image]

To find \$R_{Th}\$ we first kill all the sources. Then we have 2 paralell resistors, in series with one resistor and all of those merged are in paralell with one more resistor.
$$(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6})^{-1} + 2 = 4 \Omega$$ $$(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4})^{-1}= 2 \Omega$$
Since \$R_{Th} = R_{N}\$ we get: \$R_{Th} = R_{N} = 2 \Omega\$

If I did that correctly then I get this:

[image]

And now I am lost. When using Thévenin's Theorem we should end up with a voltage source in series with a resistor. With Norton we should end up with a current source in paralell with a resistor. I usually use source transformation but the only methods I have seen used needs a voltage source in series with a resistor or a current source in paralell with a resistor. But I have a voltage source in paralell with a resistor. What should I do to continue from here?

Comment: Try again, more carefully this time. If you short circuit the original circuit, the 3 ohm resistor will limit the current in some way or other. Your circuit reduction will deliver infinite current if short circuited. => you have done it incorrectly.

Comment: But the Vab = Vth is not equal to 20V. You need to calculate this voltage first. Take a look at this example it may help you https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/377467/why-is-the-voltage-of-a-capacitor-equal-to-the-voltage-of-a-battery-connected-it/377478#377478  Rth is indeed equal to 2 ohms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made two errors.

1. You need to calculate the thevenin voltage by finding the open-circuit (no load) output voltage of the circuit. You do this using the full schematic of the circuit, not one with the resistors reduced to the thevenin equivalent. The thevenin voltage is not simply equal to the source voltage in the original circuit.
2. You then put the equivalent resistance in series with the thevenin voltage, not in parallel.

There's no question of "what if the resistor comes out in parallel", because the procedure is to put the resistor in series and not in parallel.